# How to encoding JSONObjectWithData using UTF8?

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.5

I have this code and I'd like to use encoding to read Arabic and Emoji.

Using JSON

in .h I use two Array

```
NSArray *news;

NSMutableData *data;
```

and in .m

in viewDidLoad

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myServer.com/getmessages.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and I have use these methods

```
-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{    
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];    
}

-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{   
    [data appendData:theData];  
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

    if (news == nil || [news count] == 0) {

        UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry!!" message:@" No News !!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [errorView show];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - Plaese make sure                                            you're connected to either 3G or Wi-Fi" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [errorView show];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}
```

and I using UITableView

```
cell.newsLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Content"];
```

what is the encoding for Arabic and Emoji ? and how could I use encoding in this code

Answer (score 0):

Emoji can be used in Unicode6.0 or later(UTF8) , on iOS5 or later.